# How to create post using WordPress REST API

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have created small webpage, I want to create post using WordPress rest api, but I send data but this error displayed How do I pass data could you please check and update.

post.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var ourPostData = {
            "title" : "siva",
            "content" : "Hi this welcome",
            "status": "publish",
            'excerpt': 'Read this awesome post',
    'password': 'siva',
    'slug':'new-test-post'
        };
alert(JSON.stringify(ourPostData))
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts",
    data:JSON.stringify(ourPostData),
    dataType:"json",
    username: "siva",
  password: "siva",
    headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
  },
    contentType:"Application/json",
    success:function(callback){
      console.log(callback)
    }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You wouldn't want to do this in JavaScript, otherwise you are exposing your username/password/token to the public.

Comment: What's the error?